# How to check if a dynamically created file exists on AWS S3 using JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404

I have a server side script that dynamically creates a js file in an s3 bucket after a given url has 1 page view. The server side script runs every 1 minute.

On any given URL on the site, I have a script which tries to call this dynamically created file.

Such as:

```
var host = window.location.host;
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.async = true;
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/"+host+pathName+".js;
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(script, node);
})();
```

The problem is that if a new URL is created on the site and the first visitor goes to that page then the cron job has had a chance to run, and therefore the js file does not exist in the bucket yet. This causes a 404 error but also causes an error in the on-page javascript above crashing the js library that contains it.

Is there a way to check the existence of the file on the fly and default to a different file if the dynamically created one has not been built yet?

For example (pseudo code):

```
try{
   script.src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/"+host+pathName+".js;
}
catch(e){
   404error = true;
}
finally{
   if(404error == true){
      script.src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/DEFAULT.js";
   }
}
```

---

Updated code with calling a different file on error. This successfully calls the other file, however it also still causes a 404 error in Chrome.

```
var host = window.location.host;
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.async = true;
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onerror = function(){
   var host = window.location.host;
   var pathName = window.location.pathname;
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.async = true;
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/some_default_file.js";
   var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   node.parentNode.insertBefore(script, node);
}
script.src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/"+host+pathName+".js;
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(script, node);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `script.onerror`:

```
var pathName   = window.location.pathname;
var script     = document.createElement('script');
script.async   = true;
script.type    = 'text/javascript';
script.onerror = function() {
  console.log('script failed to load');
};
script.src     = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/" + host + pathName + ".js";
var node       = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(script, node);
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but Chrome still throws a 404. With in the onerror function I tried rerunning the script which makes the call to the default file successfully but again, the 404 is still thrown.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are saying. You cannot avoid the 404 from happening, but you *can* detect it and load another resource.